# Clicking inside window is required in order for onpaste to work

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, dynamic-html

The idea is to handle paste event at the level of page as such (contrary to handling it at the level of individual input fields/elements). The solution is to have paste event handler bound to a top level div element.

The problem is that before paste event starts to be firing, **user must first physically click anywhere inside the browser window** after the page loads for the first time (even though the browser window as such is in focus).

The question is: **How to make the page sensitive to paste without this step (of having to click inside the window)?**

Techniques I've tried that didn't work:

- Focussing the outer div programmatically on load (see the js code below)
- Clicking the outer div programmatically on load (see the js code below)

*Note: My actual project is a rather complex angular web page, fortunately, I was able to replicate the behaviour using pure HTML/javascript.*

*Note: Paste event on div seems to be working only in Chrome. So don't even try this in MSIE or FF. Nevertheless, cross browser support is another issue that I'd like to tackle separately.*

Test html page to replicate the problem:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>paste test</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }

        div#outer {
            margin: auto;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: whitesmoke;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        div#inner {
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            border: solid 3px green;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="load()">


    <div id="outer" onpaste="paste()" tabindex="1">

        First click anywhere to make the paste work.

        <div id="inner">

            Just any content.
            Not important for example.

        </div>

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">


        function load() {

            document.getElementById('outer').focus();
            document.getElementById('outer').click();
        }

        function paste() {

            alert('paste');
        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Were you able to solve the problem? I'm having the exact same bug right now.

Comment: Well to pick up a paste event, you need to be focused on that section of the page you attached the event too. Did you try to attach the event to the window @Vinch?